# PHP File send mail every time when opened explicitly

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have a contact page which made with the help of PHPMailer. The minimal code is as follows

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="Mail.php" name="contactForm">
...
</form>
```

This works perfectly fine, but whenever I try to open Mail.php explicitly on the webserver, the webserver sends `blank` email every time. Here's a screenshot of email whenever I access Mail.php [image: screenshot]

Below is the minimal code from PHPMailer's Mail.php

```
$mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = "<b>From: </b>". $sender. "<br>" ." <b>Name: </b>". $yourName. "<br>". "<b> Message Body </b>" .$message;
    $mail->AltBody = "<b>From: </b>". $sender. "<br>" ." <b>Name: </b>". $yourName. "<br>". "<b> Message Body </b>" .$message;

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } 
        else {
            echo "Message has been sent....You're being redirected.....";
            }
```

How can I restrict the user to explicitly access Mail.php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as suggested by Jiri Hrazdil and Ahmad Mobaraki, using `isset` should solve my problem, but I couldn't figure out how to implement that. So I came up with my own solution. I check, if the variables are empty in the first place, So this way if anyone directly tries to access the file it'll show a message the `Fields are empty`, This is the way I did it.

```
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$yourName = $_POST['yourName'];
$sender  = $_POST['emailID'];
$subject  = $_POST['subject'];
$message  = $_POST['message'];
$to = 'email@email.com';
header('Refresh: 5; URL=whatever.php');

if(empty($yourName) || empty($sender) || empty($subject) || empty($message) || empty($message))
{
    echo "Fields are empty";
}
else
{
    //Working Code of PHP Mailer
}
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry for being late!  `from` is not form!  it is one of your form inputs!  : `<input name="from"  type="text"> ` , you can use another field, like : `name` or `message`,  when you try to open `Mailer.php`  explicitly , none of `from` or `to` or `name` or `subject` or .... are filled with `$_POST` so there is no need to check all of them, as you did!  it is just enough to check for example `to` or `from` :  `if(isset($_POST["to"]))....`, if you want to be more specific you can put all in `if`, see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

you should check if the request is `POST` in your php file  for example:

```
if(isset($_POST['from'])){
   // send email 
}
```

when you try to open `Mailer.php` explicitly, your request is  `GET`.

**UPDATE:**

`from` is not form!  it is one of your form inputs!  : `<input name="from"  type="text">` , you can use another field, like : `name` or `message`,  when you try to open `Mailer.php`  explicitly , none of `from` or `to` or `name` or `subject` or .... are filled with `$_POST` so there is no need to check all of them!

it is just enough to check for example `to` or `from` :

```
if(isset($_POST['to'])){
   // send email 
} else {
    die("forbidden! you can not open this file explicitly!")
}
```

Comment: in your answer `from` is form name or button name?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a condition to check, whether the values from the form are filled:

```
if (isset($_POST['sender'])) {
    // send mail
}
```